# how to make a macro to generate code in a for loop?

Tags: c++, c, macros, c-preprocessor

I noticed the following code in a code review:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 50; ++i) {
  switch(i) {
    case 0:
      return f1();
    case 1:
      return f2();
    ...
    case 49:
      return f50();
  }
}
```

and I'm wondering if there's any elegant way, such as using a macro to simplify this code (reduce it to few lines):

thanks.

Comment: what effort have you made to solve the problem?

Comment: wouldn't this just simplify to calling `f1()` and return right away without doing any of the other branches?

Comment: looks like an XY problem. The best way would be to use a function pointer table instead of a macro

Comment: Why? It is perfectly readable, easy to test and the code itself can be autogenerated by a bit of python/bash/emacs or even excel. A complex array of function pointers might be shorter but source liens are cheap

Comment: Do you really have fifty methods with names like `f1` and so on? Why not just run them in order? What purpose does the loop serve?

Comment: @DanielA.White, I know someone else spent more time than he should to solve this by using macro, but no luck. I did some search but have no clue how to do it.

Comment: Why don't you have functors in a map or array?

Comment: Use a `map` instead and you can do this with a call to it's `operator[]`

Comment: As Daniel already said,it will return the result of f1() and will never loop over the other 49 functions...is the example code correct?

Comment: oh, yes, let's a bug, it always returns f1()

Comment: alright, this is a bad question, how do I close this thread ? I can not edit it

Comment: @TMS Just under the tags, after the question body, there should be small grey buttons labeled "share", "edit", "close", "delete" and "flag".

Comment: but deleting with upvoted answers isn't very nice...

Comment: Hey, you just had a nasty bug in the code found. I'd call that a win. What the solution is, who can say, but at least you know this needs a serious look-over.

Comment: A macro is *almost always* the wrong solution.

Comment: Notable exception to the above comment: http://dilbert.com/strip/1994-06-10

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 50; ++i) {
  switch(i) {
    case 0:
      return f1();
    ...
```

can be reduced to

```
return f1();
```

No macros required.

Comment: btw, there's no bug in original code, only the simplified code I post here has issues. thanks for pointing it out

Comment: @TMS To be honest, I don't quite understand why you accepted this answer then. :-)

Comment: @melpomene, I don't think I should correct my post since there're already so many discussions about the bug in the post. i would better start a new one if I still want to ask this question correctly. This answer indeed simplify the code so it's accepted.

Comment: Haha, I had to think about this for a few minutes. Nice!

Answer (score 0):

There cannot be any CPP macro to generate this, but it is common practice in C or C++ to generate stuff with something else. For example, you could trivially write in Python, Ocaml, or AWK some script which generates your code, and doing such things are common practice (you just need to add a few lines in your `Makefile` to do so). And you could also use other preprocessors, such as [m4](https://www.gnu.org/software/m4/m4.html) or [gpp](https://logological.org/gpp).

BTW, in your case, you could consider declaring an array of 50 pointer functions, and call them indirectly.